# why does postman throws 500 internal server error when sending POST request?

Tags: mysql, express, railway

It's my first time building user auth using railway MySQL database and when I make a `POST` request in Postman, it returns `500 Internal Server Error`.

I write the code in 3 files: `userRepository.js`, `userService.js` and `userController.js`.

Here is `userRepository.js`:

```js
  const User = require('../models');
  const createUser = async (data) => {
    return User.create(data)
  };

  const getUserByUsername = async (username) => {
    return User.findOne({
      where: {
       username: username,
      },
    });
  };
  
  const getUserByEmail = async (email) => {
    return User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: email,
      },
     });
  };
  
  module.exports = {
    createUser,
    getUserByUsername,
    getUserByEmail,
  };
```

Here is `userService.js`

```js
const userRepository = require('../repositories/userRepository');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const registerUser = async (data) => {
  const { username, email, password } = data;
  
  const existingUserByUsername = await userRepository.getUserByUsername(username);
  if (existingUserByUsername) {
    throw new Error('Username already exists');
  }

  const existingUserByEmail = await userRepository.getUserByEmail(email);
  if (existingUserByEmail) {
    throw new Error('Email already exists');
  }

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  const user = await userRepository.createUser({
    username,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword
  });

  return user;
};

const loginUser = async (data) => {
  const { username, password } = data;

  const user = await userRepository.getUserByUsername(username);
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error('User not found');
  }

  const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!isPasswordValid) {
    throw new Error('Invalid password');
  }

  const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, 'JWT_SECRET');
  return token;
};

module.exports = {
  registerUser,
  loginUser
};
```

And here is `userController.js`:

```js
const userService = require('../services/userService');

const register = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await userService.registerUser(req.body);
    return res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      message: 'User created successfully',
      data: user
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (
      err.message === 'Username already exists' ||
      err.message === 'Email already exists'
    ) {
      return res.status(409).json({ 
        status: 'error',
        error: err.message
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json({ 
        status: 'error',
        message: 'Internal Server Error',
        data: err
      });
    }
    next(err);
  }
};

const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = await userService.loginUser(req.body);
    return res.json({ 
      status: 'success',
      message: 'User logged in successfully',
      data: token
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (
      err.message === 'User not found' ||
      err.message === 'Invalid password' 
    ) {
      return res.status(401).json({ 
        status: 'error',
        error: err.message
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json({ 
        status: 'error',
        message: 'Internal Server Error',
        data: err
      });
    }
    next(err);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  register,
  login
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If it's your error being popped, you do pass back `data`. Anything useful in there?

Comment: i think it is being called when i try to send POST request on postman, because when i start to run this code in vscode, this code is running as it should. but i don't really sure either  @tadman

Comment: Your server or Express itself might pop a 500 if it encounters some kind of fault while processing, so it's worth seeing if this is your exception or some other one before going deeper. You could even change your 500 to a 503 and see if you get 503 all of a sudden.

Comment: Postman is not involved in any way into this question. The error is returned by the server and I bet it returns the same response when the request is issued with `curl` or other HTTP client.

Comment: i found a new error, it throws `User.findOne is not a function`, how could this happen? it is already exist in each file @tadman

Comment: Is `User` a Sequelize model?

Comment: there are some ambiguous between user and User and i just swap it. and there's a thing, it returns new error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')`. anyways, user is a sequelize model @tadman

Comment: `const User = require('../models');` is probably incorrect. It might be `const { User } = require(...)` as you need to destructure.

Comment: i just change it and it throws a new again again `string violation: username cannot be an array or an object` 

and here is what i want to put in database
```
{
    "username": "jane doe",
    "email": "janedoe@gmail.com",
    "password": "janedoe",
    "role": "customer"
}
```
and datatype of username is string @tadman

Comment: You should have a look at `req.body` and see what's in there. Maybe you're missing something in how it's structured.

Comment: it's solved and you're right, there's something wrong in req.body. thank you